What is the rationale behind mandating capital punishment for non homicide crimes or crimes that don't cause permanent unmanageable suffering?
Are the arguments in favour of this sound ? And leaving out deterrence from the equation entirely. Can capital punishment for such crimes ever be proportionate from a retributive justice perspective
Edit: I'm gonna edit this with further arguments if I can

It should be noted that many people object to capital punishment even for murder. And excluding murder, people impose capital punishment even for crimes that seem to cause no harm to anyone else (which is obviously a lot more objectionable than the thing many people already object to).

One statement I've heard often is that there is no reason to keep henious criminals alive. And that from a utilitarian perspective , they are a net negative

@ThrowawAccount There's a utilitarian cost on the executor and society as a whole, from being aware that people are being killed, and desensitising people to the idea of killing people who do things you dislike, and thinking of people who break the law as less-than-human. There's also a utilitarian cost on the criminal themselves, which people may be less concerned about, but it's still there, and it's especially relevant if the person is innocent.

It's not so much "further arguments" you need to add so much as examples. What exactly are you referring to? Julian Assamge??? One could argue he's under trial — de jure position. One could argue he's in the process of a slow excruciating death sentence — de facto situation. So, once again : Who? What?

I'm referring to the worst of the worst non homicide crimes such as Larry Nassar and the likes. I have no sympathy for his life sentence but I don't believe death is an appropriate penalty it we know that death penalty doesn't deter. I also have a problem with using "whatever the victim wants" as a sole criteria for what is proportionate because it could be used to justify any punishment for any crime based on subjectiveness or intersubjectivity.

As best as I can find,  Larry Nassar is on effective (literal) life imprisonment — multiple consecutive life terms.Not a nice thing to go through maybe but not capital (ie death) punishment. So I don't see what is the question

Is Louisiana v Kennedy a good example to add ? It involved Brutal CSA which was given the death penalty but the courts ruled against its constitutionality. Their reasoning included lack of deterrence and that death penalty for crimes that don't cause death wouldn't be appropriate

There are various retributive-justice arguments in favor of capital punishment for especially heinous crimes, none of which require that the crime be murder or leave permanent unmanageable suffering. Certain crimes shock the conscience. If the criminal raped and tortured a child, for example, a lot of people will think that execution is the only appropriate punishment regardless if the child survives will eventually recover.
First of all, there is the perceived-justice angle. Will the victim, the victim's family, and others sympathetic to the victim believe that justice has not been done if the perpetrator continues to live? If so, then there is a cost to society in not executing the perpetrator in that it will tend make people cynical about justice. "They care more about the criminal than the victim", etc. Over time, this cynicism about justice may lead to a less law-abiding population.
Second, there is the vengeance angle. If you don't punish the perpetrator sufficient to sooth the anger of the victim's family, it is more likely to create friction between the family of the victim and that of the perpetrator. Someone in the victim's family is likely to try to take vengeance on the perpetrator or someone in the perpetrator's family. Those of us raised in Western societies and not in dangerous neighborhoods often don't see the risk here because we are used to letting the government handle everything, but people who grew up in dangerous neighborhoods or non-Western societies, are far more likely to have experience taking the law into their own hands and be willing to do so. The way we broke that habit in the Western world is in part through the use of capital punishment.
Another consideration is abstract justice. If you believe that good and evil are real things, that there are real obligations and real obligatory justice, then you believe that there is simply a proper response to a heinous crime. The universe has been put out of balance by the crime and to put it back in balance, the perpetrator must lose his life. I'll also note that if you don't believe that good and evil are real, you shouldn't be concerned about capital punishment except for it's functional use. If evil isn't real, then it can't be evil to execute someone.

I do agree that this is theoretically possible for point 1 that people might break the law more. But honestly I don't think a law that protects minorities or weaker or outcasted sections of society is a justification to break it. Otherwise we could justify breaking any law that protects any minority on the sole basis that it is against the will of the majority

@ThrowawAccount, I don't understand your comment. I didn't say anything about laws that protect weaker sections of society or justify breaking of laws.

I don't see how the people that break the law because it doesn't have their desired outcome would be justified in doing so. This seems to assume that the purpose of law is purely to fulfill what the majority wants. A lot of times in history the majority have retaliated and taken law into their own hands because the law didn't support their will (such as the American civil war) doesn't mean they were justified. And doesn't mean the law cannot be successfully enforced without going against the majority.

And I don't see how capital punishment caused a reduction in vigilantism. It seems to have little to no impact on it empirically

@ThrowawAccount I didn't say vigilantism is justified without capital punishment; I said it is more likely without capital punishment. Nor did I assume the purpose of the law is to fulfill what the majority wants, but rather to be commensurate with what the majority feels is justice. What's the alternative? That an enlightened minority determines justice?

@ThrowawAccount, I don't believe you have empirical evidence for whether capital punishment had an impact on vigilantism. However, it did largely vanish in the middle and upper classes of the Western world in the last century or so, and it's at least arguable that this wouldn't have happened if people didn't see justice being done for them.

Technically human rights and judicial review do fulfill the function of curbing majority or even minority excesses. The purpose of rights exactly is this. The whole reason human rights came to exist is due to tyranny and conflicts in both majoritarian and minoritarian governments. I don't think either tyranny of the majority of tyranny of the minority justify either extreme. Technically democracy itself is a human right (in the UDHR for example)

Very rarely do people receive the death penalty in   non despot run  countries  for non homicide crimes or crimes that don't cause permanent unmanageable suffering. Despots for their part don't need a rational to kill people. If they did they wouldn't be despots.
The US Supreme court ruled in Kennedy v. Louisiana that in crimes committed against individuals the death penalty should not be given in unless  the victim’s life was  taken.
That said, although it hasn't happened recently (because very few people have been convicted for espionage  recently) the US has given the death penalty to spies for hostile countries. The Espionage act of 1917  provides that anyone convicted of transmitting or attempting to transmit to a foreign government "information relating to the national defense" may be imprisoned for life or put to death. IOW someone who caused no actual harm but tried to  be a spy can face the death penalty. There were also unsuccessful  attempts to broaden the application of this statue later to include among other things people who ratted out the identity of American spies to other countries even though doing so would pose no tangible threat to US security
The rationale for the above is fairly simple. Even though these things may have caused no harm the potential for harm is of such a great magnitude that anyone doing do so is deserving of death. Their behavior risked so many other lives
